# Open List Items as new overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a list where clicking on each of its items would open up into a new overlay, with its own overlay text.

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssinhaonline/v2gaox78/11/) for what I have tried so far, but it won't work. Ideally, clicking on `A` would open up a translucent overlay spanning the screen with `Overlay Text - A` as it's text.

I used [W3CSchools'](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_overlay_text) example for Overlay as my inspiration.

I have been coding in HTML, CSS, Javascript for a total of 3 days now, and trying to figure out stuff as much as possible. So if you find some glaring mistakes or bad coding styles, please point it out to me and I will try to make sure I follow your instructions.

Thanks!

Comment: you should consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for code review and advices, not SO

Comment: Thanks! Did not know that information. I'll do what you said. :)

Comment: I'm actually not looking for a review. I'm trying to make something work, and seeking some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kelvinsusername/xr0ed6ft/

I changed a bit of js (to use getElementById rather than getElementByClass <- I think you were going for getElementsByClass which would return a collection?):

```
document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
```

And restructured the html to have a single overlay so the onclicks aren't nested - having an onclick nested inside another element which has an onclick means both would run (unless you stopped the event propagating)

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm. Accepted your answer.

Wondering how I can make it work, if instead of duplicate `span` elements if I could call the following `div` elements by ID:

```<div id="overlay" class="overlay" onclick="off()">
    <div class=a">
        A
    </div>
    ..
</div>```

I tried JS: 
```function on(clickedValue) {
    document.getElementById(clickedValue).style.display = "block";
}```

Sadly, I feel like I'm almost there, but falling just short.

Comment: I don't totally follow what you're trying to do, but I think you what to change the <div class="a"> to <div id="a"> because your on function is using getElementById (not get by class)